# Invoking remotely a script in Google Cloud

Tags: perl, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Initially I thought of this approach: creating a full web app that would allow uploading the files into the Data Store, then Data Flow would do the ETL by reading the files from the Data Store and putting the transformed data in Cloud SQL, and then have a different section that would allow passing the query to output the results in a CSV file into the Data Store.
However I want to keep it as simple as possible, so I my idea is to create a Perl script in the Cloud that does the ETL and also another script in which you can pass a SQL query as argument and output the results in a CSV file into the Data Store. This script would be invoked remotely. The idea is to execute the script without having to install all the stack in each client (Google SQL proxy, etc.), just by executing a local script with the arguments that would be passed to the remote script.
Can this be done? If so, how? And in addition to that, does this approach makes sense?
Thanks!!